# Compare dates in the following format: Wednesday 20 August 2012 10:14

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, format

I am trying to see if the current date is new that the the date variable. However the date variable comes from an XMLFile that a user can edit and it has to be written in that format for them to read it easier etc. The format I have is:
Wednesday 22 August 2012 10:14 = ("dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm ")

How can I convert this back in to a date format so I can compare it to the current date

Or

Can I compare both dates in this format?

Comment: Nit-pick: The date is incorrect. It should be August 22nd, or a Monday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a string representing your date, you have to "parse" it.

```
Dim enus = Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
Dim d As Date = Date.ParseExact("Wednesday 22 August 2012 10:14", "dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm", enus)
```

Now you have a "date" that you can compare to any other date.

Comment: Get this error:
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.

Comment: @TeamGB - Probably because in your code you posted it is `20 Aug` not `22 Aug` as @Oded pointed out

Answer (score 2):

To convert to a date:

```
Dim theDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Wednesday 22 August 2012 10:14",
                                  "dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm",
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

To format to a string:

```
Dim dateString = theDate.ToString("dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
```

Comment: What string format would I use to get it to the default DateTime format that the computer will use?

Comment: @TeamGB - Just use `ToString()` to get the default. I will use the current culture setup for the user.

Comment: Ive used this, as the variable can sometimes change:
Dim theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToRun,
                                  "dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm",
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)


However it tells me the day of the week is incorrect

Comment: Sorry sorted it, it was becasue of the problem reported on my questions the day was incorrect with the date. Thanks very much